What is the best practice on deciding to looping a closed opportunity as new opportunity?
Management is planning to extend the whole opportunity stage to monitoring as to when a customer stopped engaging to our product.
The pipelines starts with new customers coming in as interested then closes when they made their first purchase.
So what will happen is they want to keep it open and extend the opportunity to monitor them up until 2 months to see if they will make a purchase again (so there will be constant engagement like calls or emails) and if not will mark them as churned customers.
If churn, another set of action will be done until re-purchase.
I was thinking of closing the opportunity the moment they made the first purchase and then create a new case over new opportunity instead (maybe 2 cases for pre-churn and churn) to separate the after sales.
How do you guys usually go around this?

The standard recommendation would be to make renewal opportunities, so that you have accurate data for reporting and tracking purposes. There's a reason why Opportunities are called "opportunities," and not "sales." Keeping this data in opportunities also allows you to forecast revenue. As far as the ancillary data, like followups, consider using campaigns so you can keep track of how much effort is going into particular strategies and determine your return over investment for each strategy.
